# Ubuntu Apache2 add SSL certificate with port 80

Tags: 20.04, apache2, ssl

I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and the Apache2 service. How I can add an SSL certificate using port 80 only, as I don't have any option to use other ports?

Comment: SSL is expected to operate on port 443. If you *must* use port 80, your visitors will need to include the port in each request, like: https://yoursite.com:80/whatever . If this is acceptable, then you can add the SSL certificate to your existing Apache vhost configuration 

Comment: ok understood and thanks for your clarification. Appreciated !!!

Comment: wierd that you want this, I am currently looking for a solution to fix this. I have to visit https://mywebsite.com:80/ for https to work